# Tips on how to make a GitHub action faster

Tags: node.js, github-actions

I have a GitHub action responsible for compiling/bundling a set of JS/TS files together (using SWC "Spack" mode) and sending them to an AWS S3 bucket.

Currently, the step "build-and-deploy" takes an average of 60 seconds, I'm looking at ways to improve that.

Here are some more details about what steps take time:

[image]

I only care about improving the "build-and-deploy" job.

---

[image]

The build of the "s3-sync-action" is what takes the most time (24s), but I'm not sure I can do anything about that directly.

The "Build distributable" takes up to 15s in some case, I think I could start with that.

---

[image]

---

Here goes the GitHub action:

```
name: Bundle distributable
on:
  push:

jobs:
  # Builds the new distributable files (.js) and commit them to the repo
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Expose GitHub slug/short variables # See https://github.com/rlespinasse/github-slug-action#exposed-github-environment-variables
        uses: rlespinasse/github-slug-action@v3.x # See https://github.com/rlespinasse/github-slug-action

      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Build distributable
        run: NODE_ENV=production yarn install --production --frozen-lockfile && yarn build

      - name: Upload files to AWS S3 and CloudFront and invalidate CF cache
        if: env.GITHUB_REF_SLUG == 'main' # If main, deploy on S3 and invalidate cache (otherwise, don't deploy anything)
        uses: kefranabg/s3-sync-action@02d8eaf34efb8bd76abe2e5614ba3d8028de219e # https://github.com/kefranabg/s3-sync-action - Same as https://github.com/jakejarvis/s3-sync-action but invalidates the cache automatically - See https://github.com/jakejarvis/s3-sync-action/issues/63
        with:
          args: --acl public-read --follow-symlinks --delete
        env:
          AWS_S3_BUCKET: ''
          AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ''
          AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ''
          AWS_REGION: '' # The region where was created the bucket
          SOURCE_DIR: 'dist' # We only store the distributed files
          DEST_DIR: '' # XXX Store the files in a folder dedicated to the client
          DISTRIBUTION_ID: '' # ID of the CloudFront distribution to invalidate (resets cache)
```

---

A few thoughts:

- I'm using Yarn to do package install, maybe I could switch to something faster?
- I'm using SWC to do the build (Spack mode), and I don't think I can change that easily, I used Spack mode to build multiple outputs, each using a different entry.
- Maybe using a higher Node.js version would speed things, too? Currently using v12.